# Uploading an image from Java desktop Application to PHP-Server through web-services

Tags: java, php, web-services

1. pick image form System..

   ```
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
   String imageName=f.getName();

   try {
       ImageIcon ii;
       ii = new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath())));
       jLabel2.setIcon(ii);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. upload data to Server through Web Service

   ```
   List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", AuthConstants.id));
   nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile_pic",imageName));
   nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile_pic_path",filename));

   try {
       StringBuilder s = (StringBuilder) HttpWebService.postWebService(nvps, "services", "setting_update");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"pic data  :"  );
       System.out.println("File uploaded: " );
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"profile pic upload done (y)");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

Comment: so what is the Error ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: php developer says that there are no tmp_name you provided so how i can give tmp_name via webservice@MurtazaKhursheedHussain